# Intel NCS Movidius Installation Error - ncsdk_redirector.txt not found

Tags: ncsdk

When I'm trying to install in Ubuntu 17.10, I get this error:

> 2018-03-14 11:14:54 ERRO 403: Forbidden.
>   ./install.sh: line 20: ncsdk_redirector.txt: file or directory not found
>   wget: missing URL

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
The previous version is available now, but the current is not:

http://ncs-forum-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/ncsdk/ncsdk_01_10/ncsdk_redirector.txt

http://ncs-forum-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/ncsdk/ncsdk_01_12/ncsdk_redirector.txt

It seems like they are doing some update.

You can create ncsdk_redirector.txt file in the install directory with the following content manually:

```
http://ncs-forum-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/ncsdk/ncsdk_01_12/NCSDK-1.12.00.01.tar.gz
```

Then the installer will be able to pick it up

Comment: Thanks, Sergei. Problem solved! But it's disappointing an error like this, caused by the product developer. It certainly reduces the reliability and popularity of the product in the community. I hope they give more attention to support this device. Thanks again!